# How to merge two different array of objects using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects

I have two different array of objects.And i have to merge the two array of objects in nested way.

```
var array1=[{ PersonalID: '11', qusetionNumber: '1', value: 'Something' },
                { PersonalID: '12', qusetionNumber: '2', value: 'whatever' },
                { PersonalID: '13', qusetionNumber: '3', value: 'anything' },
                { PersonalID: '14', qusetionNumber: '4', value: 'null' }];

var array2=[{ qusetionNumber: '2', chID: '111', cValue: 'red' },
            { qusetionNumber: '2', chID: '112', cValue: 'green'},
            { qusetionNumber: '2', chID: '113', cValue: 'blue' },
            {qusetionNumber: '3', choiceID: '114', cValue: 'yellow'},
            {qusetionNumber: '4', choiceID: '115', cValue: 'red'}];
```

the Output should be  In this format So how to make it using loop or underscore?
    OUTPUT

```
  personalID:[{
            personalID:11,
            qusetionNumber:1,
            value: 'Something' 
           },
               {
            personalID:12,
            qusetionNumber:2,
            value: 'whatever',
            choice:[                        
                { qusetionNumber: '2', chID: '111', cValue: 'red' },
                        { qusetionNumber: '2', chID: '112', cValue: 'green'},
                        { qusetionNumber: '2', chID: '113', cValue: 'blue' }
                ] 
           },
           {
            personalID:13,
            qusetionNumber:3,
            value: 'anything',
            choice:[                        
                { qusetionNumber: '3', chID: '114', cValue: 'yellow' }
                           ] 
               },
               {
            personalID:14,
            qusetionNumber:4,
            value: 'null',
            choice:[                        
                { qusetionNumber: '4', chID: '115', cValue: 'red' }
                           ] 
               }]
```

Comment: i have tried using forloop but i am not getting the proper result

Comment: `groupBy` on the array2, followed by `map` on array1

Comment: can you please share the code how you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table as reference to the right `questionNumber` and build a new property `choice` if necessary.

```js
var array1 = [{ PersonalID: '11', questionNumber: '1', value: 'Something' }, { PersonalID: '12', questionNumber: '2', value: 'whatever' }, { PersonalID: '13', questionNumber: '3', value: 'anything' }, { PersonalID: '14', questionNumber: '4', value: 'null' }],
    array2 = [{ questionNumber: '2', chID: '111', cValue: 'red' }, { questionNumber: '2', chID: '112', cValue: 'green' }, { questionNumber: '2', chID: '113', cValue: 'blue' }, { questionNumber: '3', choiceID: '114', cValue: 'yellow' }, { questionNumber: '4', choiceID: '115', cValue: 'red' }],
    hash = Object.create(null);

array1.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a.questionNumber] = a;
});

array2.forEach(function (a) {
    if (hash[a.questionNumber]) {
        hash[a.questionNumber].choice = hash[a.questionNumber].choice || [];
        hash[a.questionNumber].choice.push(a);
    }
});

console.log(array1);
```

Comment: hash[a.questionNumber].choice = hash[a.questionNumber].choice || [];                                                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'choice' of undefined     its giving the above error

Comment: you can add a check if the `questionNumber` reference exists.

Comment: i have resolve the error but i am not able to get all the choice..means for the personalID:'12' i am getting all the choice but for others i am not getting

Comment: maybe it's because i changed the property name to `questionNumber`, without typo.

Comment: The same problem i am facing

Comment: please add your try to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the following manner using only vanilla JS.

Sample in modern ES6+

```
var array3 = array1.map(question => {
    let newQuestion = Object.assign({},question);   // In order not to mutate the items array1
    newQuestion.choice = array2.filter(choice => choice.qusetionNumber === question.qusetionNumber);
    return newQuestion;
});
```

Older syntax:

```
var array3 = array1.map(function(question) {
    var newQuestion = Object.assign({},question);   // In order not to mutate the items array1
    newQuestion.choice = array2.filter(function(choice){ return choice.qusetionNumber === question.qusetionNumber});
    return newQuestion;
});
```

If you cannot count on Object.assign being available, you can use the assign function in lodash or extend in underscore or jQuery

```js
var array1 = [{
  PersonalID: '11',
  qusetionNumber: '1',
  value: 'Something'
}, {
  PersonalID: '12',
  qusetionNumber: '2',
  value: 'whatever'
}, {
  PersonalID: '13',
  qusetionNumber: '3',
  value: 'anything'
}, {
  PersonalID: '14',
  qusetionNumber: '4',
  value: 'null'
}];

var array2 = [{
  qusetionNumber: '2',
  chID: '111',
  cValue: 'red'
}, {
  qusetionNumber: '2',
  chID: '112',
  cValue: 'green'
}, {
  qusetionNumber: '2',
  chID: '113',
  cValue: 'blue'
}, {
  qusetionNumber: '3',
  choiceID: '114',
  cValue: 'yellow'
}, {
  qusetionNumber: '4',
  choiceID: '115',
  cValue: 'red'
}];

var array3 = array1.map(function(question) {
  var newQuestion = Object.assign({}, question); // In order not to mutate the items array1
  newQuestion.choice = array2.filter(function(choice) {
    return choice.qusetionNumber === question.qusetionNumber
  });
  return newQuestion;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(array3, null, 4));
```

Result:

`[
    {
        "PersonalID": "11",
        "qusetionNumber": "1",
        "value": "Something",
        "choice": []
    },
    {
        "PersonalID": "12",
        "qusetionNumber": "2",
        "value": "whatever",
        "choice": [
            {
                "qusetionNumber": "2",
                "chID": "111",
                "cValue": "red"
            },
            {
                "qusetionNumber": "2",
                "chID": "112",
                "cValue": "green"
            },
            {
                "qusetionNumber": "2",
                "chID": "113",
                "cValue": "blue"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "PersonalID": "13",
        "qusetionNumber": "3",
        "value": "anything",
        "choice": [
            {
                "qusetionNumber": "3",
                "choiceID": "114",
                "cValue": "yellow"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "PersonalID": "14",
        "qusetionNumber": "4",
        "value": "null",
        "choice": [
            {
                "qusetionNumber": "4",
                "choiceID": "115",
                "cValue": "red"
            }
        ]
    }
]`

Comment: Except PersonID:'12 'I amn't  getting the choice for others.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, maybe it will be helpful

```
var array1=[{ PersonalID: '11', qusetionNumber: '1', value: 'Something' },
                { PersonalID: '12', qusetionNumber: '2', value: 'whatever' },
                { PersonalID: '13', qusetionNumber: '3', value: 'anything' },
                { PersonalID: '14', qusetionNumber: '4', value: 'null' }];
var array2=[{ qusetionNumber: '2', chID: '111', cValue: 'red' },
            { qusetionNumber: '2', chID: '112', cValue: 'green'},
            { qusetionNumber: '2', chID: '113', cValue: 'blue' },
            {qusetionNumber: '3', choiceID: '114', cValue: 'yellow'},
            {qusetionNumber: '4', choiceID: '115', cValue: 'red'}];

var i = -1;
array1.forEach(function(a){ 
var arrayWithQuestions = [];
  array2.forEach(function(y){
    if(a.qusetionNumber == y.qusetionNumber){
      i++;
      arrayWithQuestions.push(array2[i]);          
    }
  })
  if(arrayWithQuestions.length!=0){
    a.choice = arrayWithQuestions;
  }  
  console.log(arrayWithQuestions);  
})
console.log('how array1 looks like');
console.log(array1);
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "PersonalID":"11",
        "qusetionNumber":"1",
        "value":"Something"
    },
    {
        "PersonalID":"12",
        "qusetionNumber":"2",
        "value":"whatever",
        "choice":[
            {"qusetionNumber":"2","chID":"111","cValue":    "red"},
            {"qusetionNumber":"2",  "chID":"112","cValue":"green"},
            {"qusetionNumber":"2", "chID":"113",    "cValue":"blue"}
            ]
    },
    {
        "PersonalID":"13",
        "qusetionNumber":"3",
        "value":"anything",
        "choice":   [
            {"qusetionNumber":"3", "choiceID":"114", "cValue":"yellow"}
        ]
    },
    {
    "PersonalID":"14",
    "qusetionNumber":"4",
    "value":"null",
    "choice":   [
        {"qusetionNumber":"4", "choiceID":"115", "cValue":"red"}
        ]
    }
]
```

[see jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vtrd3b55/)